# Encrypt files using gpg and hmac-sha2-256

Tags: batch-file, encryption, hmac

I wrote a script to encrypt a file using gpg, in a .bat script which takes in a filename passed from a powershell script. This is my .bat file (the important parts anyway):

```
gpg --batch --yes --passphrase "C:\users\me\Desktop\testkey.txt" --gen-key 
"C:\users\me\Desktop\SetEncryptionSettings.txt"

gpg --batch --yes -r myuser--output %OutputParam% --encrypt %1
```

where SetEncryptionSettings.txt looks like this:

```
Key-Type: default
Subkey-Type: default
Name-Real: myuser
Name-Comment: nocomment
Name-Email: me@gmail.com
Expire-Date: 0
```

And this works.  I can decrypt the file myself.  However, I sent my file to someone else who appears to be using a different decryption algorithm...he says I should use hmac-sha2-256.

I understand the encryption options in a .bat file to provide these four options:

```
(1) RSA and RSA (default)
(2) DSA and Elgamal
(3) DSA (sign only)
(4) RSA (sign only)
```

which can be seen here, for example:

https://yanhan.github.io/posts/2017-09-27-how-to-use-gpg-to-encrypt-stuff.html

So I thought that my code was using RSA since that's the default...and that since there are no options here for hmac-sha2-256, I'm going to have to change everything now. Can I make this work using a similar setup to what I have now, without downloading any additional programs?

Comment: I'm not understanding the need for the batch file. `gpg.exe` is a standard executable file, there's no obvious reason not to run it directly inside your PowerShell script.

Comment: You mean call gpg from within the powershell script?  Well maybe I could, I've already spent so much time dong it the way I did it so I'd rather not totally rewrite things...but would that solve the hmac-sha2-256 problem?  I only have powershell 2.0 on my server from where this script is run.  I'm calling the application from an external program which tends to have issues calling other programs, but I know it works with .bat scripts.

Comment: There's nothing to change really, create the variable `$OutputParam` in PowerShell and add the two commands as you would in a batch file. However, the functionality of the executable, `gpg.exe` will not change, if it doesn't work, changing the interface will not fix it.

Comment: So, making this change will allow me to encrypt a file using hmac-sha2-256?

Comment: HMAC-SHA-256 - as it should be spelled - is a hash based MAC, a message authentication code. It does not encrypt. I guess you should go back to the other party and ask for a clarification or an example, because this will get you nowhere flat. *You cannot decide on a protocol by just tossing algorithms to each other*.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes, that's helpful to know. I will follow up on that!